# What is the purpose of files whose name starts with .xauth in Linux home directory? Is it safe to delete them?

Tags: centos, administrator, centos-7, xauth, sysadmin

I have lots of files (about 40) starting .xauth. Many of them are a few months old. What is their purpose? Is it safe to remove them?

The operating system is CentOS 7. Some file name examples: .xauthbkGARg, .xauthgFQRvt, .xauthzbfaFP

Comment: The title and text do not match – please check which is correct. Also, please provide a few example file names.

Comment: @DanielB I have checked and fixed the typo. Thanks. Some file names: .xauthbkGARg,  .xauthgFQRvt,  .xauthzbfaFP

Answer (score 2):

You perhaps mean the `.Xauthority.*` files?

This is handled in the post
[Why do I have so many .Xauthority.* files in my home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299127/why-do-i-have-so-many-xauthority-files-in-my-home-directory)

The answer is that these are the "cookies" of the X client to allow
connection to the X server (displays), as explained in the
[wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RemoteXHowTo).

If this is also your problem, you may delete them, as if you don't #
have a cookie to connect to an X server, you will create a new one
when connecting.

I would suggest as first step to move them elsewhere, until you are
sure that this didn't cause any problem.

Comment: the files start with .xauth and then some random list of characters. THere is no file that actually starts with .Xauthority.